# This is right way for database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

i have some issue with database.

Okay, i have two models -> `Page` and `Item`.
Page for displaying some content.
`Item` -> this is item discription.

So, i work on small ecommerce `shop`.

Okay, all of this models can have some comments.

So, this is my Comments model at this moment:

Comments ->

```
string : id
text : body
integer : page_id
integer : item_id
```

So when some one add comment to page -> page_id will be filled with current Page id.

And if some one add comment to item -> item_id will be filled.

Okay, i know what the best way is to create `STI` or `Polymorphic` assoc, but does i really need this way for my situation?

Sorry for my bad english, i'm from Russia.=)

Comment: Just as an aside, I've always found it best in my experience to use INT or BIGINT for ID fields... preferably with an auto-increment if available (though there are a FEW limited scenarios where auto-increment is not desirable).

Comment: What is wrong with `STI` or `Polymorphic` ?

Answer (score 1):

Although the way you have your tables and models works for you, you should consider using `polymorphic`. You don't **have** to use it, but I believe this is the most recommended way.

To use the `polymorphic associations` you'll need to change your models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

and your `comments` table, that will have this columns now:

```
integer : id # should be integer, not string
text    : body
integer : commentable_id
string  : commentable_type
```

Hope it helps...